# Soundpool to file

Tags: android

I've got a SoundPool[] that I use to play mixed audio files.
Soundpools play together without any problem, and it's very efficient!
Very briefly:

```
    private SoundPool[] sound = new SoundPool[C.ROWS];
    // every sound is initizialized with a load()
    // and when asked...
public void play(int row, int variation) {
    if (mute[row]) return;
    if (variation != 0)
        sound[row].play(variation_scheme[row][variation-1], volume[row], volume[row], PRI, 0, 1f);
}
```

This is just to show! :)
I don't put other pieces of code because everything works very fine and it is not really a problem.
My question, instead, is:

how can I redirect the whole output of the application to a file, instead of (or in addition to) the audio speaker?
In other words, there are two main solutions:
1. how can I instruct AudioPool to play() the sounds to a file instead of to an audio device?
2. or how can I redirect all the audio output of my app (or even of all the phone) to a file?

Thank you.

Comment: For part 2 of your question the answer is "You can't". Or to be precise, you can't do it for all audio played on the phone. To save just the audio being played by your own app the basic approach would be write PCM data to a file (or to an encoder which in turn writes the data to a file) in parallel to writing it to an AudioTrack or playing it through a SoundPool. This requires that your audio has been decoded to raw PCM, and if you ever play multiple sounds at the same time you'll also have to take care of mixing them before writing them to disk.

Comment: Thanks Michael, at least now I know what I was suspecting. Do you know if there are free libs for encoding / managing / mixing audio, out there? And yes, I use wav files, so it's raw PCM, but it's not quite so easy anyway... for example mixing audio files I suspect that it's not just adding bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found how to record audio is by recording each information of the sound being press such as, duration (using mediaplayer), soundID, millisecond time stamp to do play back to the millisecond, volume, rate (if needed). Then write these to a text file (internally or externally) for later use. Create a play back system that decodes that saved information from text file and organize it in some arrays or hashmaps and play back throught some sort of play back method with maybe using a handler and postDelay to play sound and desired time and then plug in necessary data to play sound from array or hashmap.

In this way you can have your own data files for playing sound sequences.